# Sending html anchors text as a parameter to onclick func. c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, onclick, commandargument

I've been trying to send a parameter to onclick func. Look at my code, there is a foreach there. This is for creating `<li>` related database. This Item coming from database. I want to use it again in delete buttons onclick. It must be come from on buttons `<li>`'s anchor. Or it could be from foreach i dont know. Problem: i dont know how i can send that string(Item) to my onclick function.

`<div id="depListId" class="panel">
          <ul id="depUl" class="list-group" runat="server">
          <% foreach (var Item in dep) { %>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a><%= Item %></a><asp:Button runat="server" class="deleteButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval(??HERE??)%>' OnCommand="delete_button" Text="Delete" /></li>
  <% } %>
        </ul>
        </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a repeater control for this:

**.ASPX:**

```
<div id="depListId" class="panel">
    <ul id="depUl" class="list-group" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <a><%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %></a>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" class="deleteButton" 
                        CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' 
                        OnCommand="delete_button" 
                        Text="Delete" />
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public List<string> dep { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dep = new List<string> { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
        Repeater1.DataSource = dep;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void delete_button(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly working. (Sorry for this late feedback) Thank u Mr. Wessels.

Answer (score 0):

the 1st argument in your server onclick method is the button control (object sender), so cast it to your button and aks for its attributes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I still dont know how to get that anchors text.

Comment: try looking at `((Button)Sender).Attributes`

Comment: I cant figured out it. It's been a day im looking that. (Also i tryed attributes this morning) Look at my code. There is eval in there. I think if i can send the Item with that, it will be great